# How to keep the application alive without a client

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My goal is to send an email out every 5 min from my application even if there isn't a browser open to the application.

I'm using [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler) to manage the tasks; which works up until the server decides to kill the application from inactivity.

My big constraints are:

- I can't touch the server. It is how it is and I have to work around it.
- I can't rely on a client refreshing a browser or anything else along the lines of using client side scripts.
- I can't use any scheduler that uses a database.

What I have been focusing on is trying to create an artificial postback.

*Note: The server is load balanced, so a solution could use that*

Is there any way that I can keep my application from getting killed by the server?

Comment: Why can't you touch the server?  Is it hosted by a third party provider?

Comment: Under what condition exactly is your process killed?

Comment: I can't touch the server as its for government and not a fully approved project, and in this area it takes explicit production critical situation for them to consider changing anything.

Comment: I believe the process is killed by a session timeout as it's always killed at the 20 min mark after a browser is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a monitoring service like https://www.pingdom.com/ to ping the server at regular intervals.  Just make sure it hits an endpoint that invokes .NET code and not a static resource.

Comment: The application I'm using is a custom built monitoring service, but I believe I'm doing essential that now, and it seems to be working.
I exposed a web method in the application and call it every 9 minuets with Fluent Scheduler. However the proccess seems to still die at 10pm every night, I am assuming the server is running a job and I won't have any way around that.